# Cannot find name 'console'

Tags: meteor, typescript, angular, angular2-meteor

I am using Angular2-Meteor, TypeScript. (Meteor version 1.3.2.4)

When I use `console.log('test');` on the **server side**, it is working well.

However, I got this warning in my terminal:

> Cannot find name 'console'.

How can I get rid of this warning?

Or is there any special method such as `Meteor.log` for server side? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@barbatus who is main contributor for angular2-meteor, gave the answer on Github.

The issue is in that TypeScript package uses lib.core.ts default lib on the server side which doesn't have definitions for console. NodeJS definitions from other side as now defines console in the global scope only (i.e. global.console).

The solution is running this in your terminal:

```
typings install registry:env/meteor --ambient
```

Please go [here](https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor/issues/246) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I get rid of this warning?

if its a TypeScript compiler warning (and not a runtime one) then `console` is defined in `lib.d.ts` : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html

Make sure that the compiler is setup correctly (e.g. doesn't have `--noLib` or some custom *incorrect* `--lib`). You might want to look at your `tsconfig.json`'s `compilerOptions` (if any)

Comment: You mention, `incorrect --lib`.  Do you know which lib contains the `console` definition?